# Questions on setting up a Play! application on a linux server

Tags: linux, git, playframework

I have been trying to figure out how to set up a Play! application on a Centos server but am running into several issues which I can't resolve.

- I am using git and have a working Play! application on my local machine which I want to deploy to my server.
- I have initialised a bare git repository in `/home/git` on my server using `git init --bare` and have pushed just the commit data to this bare repo using `git push production +master:refs/heads/master` as advised in [this tutorial](http://sebduggan.com/blog/deploy-your-website-changes-using-git/).
- The plan is to use a git hook to automatically checkout my application to my website root whenever I deploy to production.(so note that the `/home/git` directory that my bare git repository is in is not my web root)

So my questions at this stage are:

1. Which directory should my Play! application be deployed to on my server? I have read that `var/www/html` is traditional for websites with only 1 website running at a particular ip address.
2. I will not be using an apache server, just the default Play! distribution. But I remember when setting up an apache server we define the DocumentRoot. I think I am right in saying that this defines where any request to the root of http://www.mydomain.com will be routed. As I am not using Apache, how do I define that routing for the Play! application?
3. For a Play! application, which user should own the web root directory?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2):

For git I'd suggest to use [**gitolite**](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) it's litgh, but allows to manage many git accounts and user access and permissions by simple config file.

For questions:

1. It doesn't matter at all, you can use ANY folder to which you have access (even via sudo). *DocumentRoot* is typical for common HTTP servers. For Java program of any kind more important is used **port** on which you start your app. If you want to start application on port 80, you need to do it via sudo. To start more applications on port 80 in different domains you need to install HTTP server (ie. nginx or Apache) and use it reverse proxy possibilities in block's/vhost's config. Anyway used folder still doesn't matter.
2. As mentioned `DocumentRoot` is Apache's directive
3. There's no root directory ... again...

Play serves all resources by own process, doesn't serve anything directly from file storage, so your files are as save as your own app allows for that (especially if you have not any HTTP server on the machine running)

On the other hand, this way you can't run more applications responding at port 80, also eats processor each time for handling static assets, like css files, public images etc. Therefore I definitely prefer to use some HTTP as a *reverse proxy/load balancer* and server for static files. This way I can place several domains on one host, also HTTP server somehow serves files faster and don't disturbs  main app by sending it to browsers.